# BeautifulSoup no attribute found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a text file of IP addresses with each one in its own row.  The below script will run through the list and query the site to look for domains that match the IPs and print them to a file.  If every IP has a result, this works fine but when the site doesn't return a domain, I get the below error that `BeautifulSoup` can't match the attribute and the script fails.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

I tried to throw an if statement in there but couldn't get it to work.

How can I make my script print 'no result' and continue through the rest of the IPs if no domain is found in that attribute?

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import StringIO

ipfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in ipfile:
    line = line.strip()
    site = 'http://bgp.he.net/ip/' + line + '#_dns'
    #print site

    s = StringIO.StringIO(site)
    for line2 in s: 
        req = urllib2.Request(line2)
        req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0')
        html = urllib2.urlopen(req)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
        #print soup.prettify()
        results = soup.find("div", {"id": "dns"}).a.contents
        results = '\n'.join(results)
        print results

        f = open('out.txt', 'a')
        print >>f, results
        f.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `try` / `except` for [error handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    #print soup.prettify()
    results = soup.find("div", {"id": "dns"}).a.contents
    results = '\n'.join(results)
    print results

    f = open('out.txt', 'a')
    print >>f, results
    f.close
except:
    print 'No result'
```

If any error occurs in the `try` block, then it will immediately stop, and go to `except` block. This will let your code carry on, without having everything stop.

If you want to get really specific, you can tell python to only handle the exception if it's of a certain type, in this case you could do:

`except AttributeError:` instead of `except:`

Comment: Thanks!  I will read up further on error handling for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/except , excepting AttributeError only (It is bad to catch them all , since you would be ignoring potential bugs, if you catch them all) , Example -

```
try:
    results = soup.find("div", {"id": "dns"}).a.contents
    results = '\n'.join(results)
    print results
    with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
        print >>f, results
except AttributeError:
    print '<Message when no <a> tag found inside `div` with `id` dns>'
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance as well!